# Is there a way to make this query more efficient?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

This is my query:

```
SELECT
'ride_id' AS column, COUNT(*) AS null_count
FROM 
  divvy_tripdata.all_rides 
WHERE 
  ride_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
'rideable_type' AS column, COUNT(*) AS null_count
FROM 
  divvy_tripdata.all_rides 
WHERE 
  rideable_type IS NULL
```

The desired output:
[image]

I want to query the number of null values in each column of the table and the code above works, but is there any way to make the code more efficient and readable? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably not if you want the data as 2 rows. If you are ok with the data as a single row then probably - you could then UNPIVOT it but that may not be faster than your current query

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH sample_data AS (
  select NULL as col1, 1 as col2
)
SELECT COUNTIF(col1 IS NULL) as col1,
       COUNTIF(col2 IS NULL) as col2
FROM sample_data
```

Looks more readable. The efficiency might depend on the number of columns because you do not need to apply WHERE statement to every column here.

Answer (score 0):

*Indeed, if you have a high number of columns, your query will become hard to write, read and maintain.*

I suggest to **programmatically generate your query** and execute it with `execute immediate` sql command.

The following should work:

```
execute immediate (

  with queries as (

    select format(
      '''
      select
        "%s" as column,
        countif(`%s` is null) as null_count
      from `divvy_tripdata.all_rides`
      ''',
      column_name,
      column_name
    ) as query
    from `divvy_tripdata`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    where table_name = 'all_rides'

  )

  select array_to_string(
    array_agg(query), 
    '\nunion all\n'
  )
  from queries
  
)
```

---

**How it works**

1. We get the table columns from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
2. For each column we generate the query to get the `column` and `null_count`
3. We concatenate all the column queries using `union all` between each query.
4. We execute the global query with `execute immediate`.

---

**With a destination table**

For further analysis you may want to write the result in a destination table. To do so, replace the first line:

```
execute immediate (
```

by

```
execute immediate 'create or replace table DATASET.DESTINATION_TABLE as ' || (
```

---

**Efficiency**

Regarding efficiency, I think we cannot do better.

Answer (score 0):

Try below alternative (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT column, COUNT(*) AS null_counts
FROM sample_data z,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(z), r'"([^"]+)":null')) column
GROUP BY column
```

If applied to dummy data as in your example

```
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT NULL AS ride_id, 1 AS rideable_type UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, NULL
)
```

output is

[image]